# Create Table in Access with identity value

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to make a query in witch it creates a simple table, In SQL that would be:

```
CREATE TABLE RealInventry (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,PartNumber varchar(255),QTY varchar(255),Locator varchar(255))
```

I'm trying to do the same it Access DB, but I'm getting an error in "IDENTITY" syntax. How can I make this SQL query work on Access, I'm currently using Access 2013

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Autoincrement instead of Identity:

```
CREATE TABLE test (ID AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,PartNumber varchar(255),QTY varchar(255),Locator varchar(255))
```

Comment: Just tried it, Works Great, thank for the fast response @aehiilrs